# WordPress как вывести категории товаров и кликнув по ним переходить на страницу с товарами этой категории

Tags: wordpress

сайт на Wordpress.
у меня есть произвольный тип записи (goods_post_type)
и произвольные таксономии (category_goods)
они связаны.

вот создаю таксономию. Всё как обычно.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomy' );
function create_taxonomy(){
    // список параметров: http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_taxonomy_labels
    register_taxonomy('category_goods', array('goods_post_type'), array(
        'label'                 => 'Категория товара', // определяется параметром $labels->name
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'              => 'Категория',
            'singular_name'     => 'Категория товара',
            'search_items'      => 'Поиск категорий товара',
            'all_items'         => 'Все категории товаров',
            'view_item '        => 'Показать категорию товара',
            'parent_item'       => 'Родительская',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская',
            'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать категорию товара',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить категорию товара',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую категорию товара',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Новое имя Категории товара',
            'menu_name'         => 'Категории товаров',
        ),
        'description'           => '', // описание таксономии
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_in_rest'          => null, // добавить в REST API
        'slug'                  => null,
        'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'query_var'             => 'goods_taxonomy', // название параметра запроса
        'capabilities'          => array(),
        'meta_box_cb'           => null, // callback функция. Отвечает за html код метабокса (с версии 3.8): post_categories_meta_box или post_tags_meta_box. Если указать false, то метабокс будет отключен вообще
        'show_admin_column'     => true, // Позволить или нет авто-создание колонки таксономии в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
        '_builtin'              => false,
        'show_in_quick_edit'    => null, // по умолчанию значение show_ui
    ) );
}

add_action('init','good_cat_for_goods');
function good_cat_for_goods(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category_goods','good_cat_for_goods');
}
?>
```

у меня есть страница. шаблон page-goods.php
 там я вывожу свои категории.

```
   <?php 
      $categories = get_categories( array(

                   'taxonomy'     => 'category_goods',

                    'type'         => 'goods_post_type',

                     ) );
    ?>

 <?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
            <?php 
              debug(get_category_link($category->term_id));
              // debug($category);

            ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 margin-col">
              <div class="goods-categories-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
                  <a href="#">
                          <?php 
                    $id_img = get_term_meta($category->term_id,'id-cat-images', true); 
                    if(!empty($id_img)){
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image($id_img,'full');
                    }else{
                      echo '<img src="empty.jpg" alt="">';
                    }
                  ?> 
                 </a>
                 <div><?php echo $category->name;?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

а вот дебаг 1-й категории(может понадобится)

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 10
    [name] => Блины
    [slug] => bliny
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 10
    [taxonomy] => category_goods
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 12
    [filter] => raw
    [cat_ID] => 10
    [category_count] => 12
    [category_description] => 
    [cat_name] => Блины
    [category_nicename] => bliny
    [category_parent] => 0
)
```

Как вывести ссылки категорий, которые ведут на страницу с записями этих категорий?

debug(get_category_link($category->term_id)) выводит ссылки, но когда я перехожу по ним ни чего не найдено мне говорит WP.

Как это реализовать ? вывел категории(на странице где находятся только категории). кликнул категорию перешел на страницу с товарами этой категории.

помогите плз. запутался :c

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92574/discussion-on-question-by-plaglamist-wordpress------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Кратко

Вместо `get_category_link` используйте `get_term_link($id,'category_goods')`

## Полный ответ

Если покапаться в ядре WP или документации (я препочитаю [wp-kama](https://wp-kama.ru)), то можно понять, что категория также регистрируется через `register_taxonomy` :

**wp-includes/taxonomy.php**

```
60: register_taxonomy('category','post',...)
```

Тоесть привычные категории ничем не отличаются отличаются от кастомных древовидных таксов. Но чтобы с ними было чуть приятнее взаимодействовать, вокруг стандартных таксов сделали обретку и чтобы получить различные данные категории мы используем не `_term_` функции, а `_category_`. При создании своих таксов можно создать свои обертки, например для вашего случая:

```php
function get_category_goods_link($id) {
    return get_term_link($id,'category_goods');
}
```

Comment: сделал как вы сказали. перешел по ссылке, WP говорит ничего не найдено. С чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: @plaglamist уберите параметр `query_var` из `register_taxonomy('category_goods'(...`, должно помочь. Есле нет, скиньте какую ссылку возвращает функция

Comment: https://dargor.info/goods/      -- на этой странице сделал дебаг этого кода debug(get_category_goods_link($category->term_id));
             debug($category);

Comment: очень интересно. когда убираю query_var переходит на главную страницу. но ссылка остается /category_goods/bliny/